# Getting Error object reference not set to an instance of the object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I'm creating windows form speech recolonization application but somehow not able to fix the object reference issue:
Can anyone please tell where I'm going wrong, as I'm getting Getting Error object reference not set to an instance of the object in the below code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        Choices list;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            try
            {
                list.Add(new string[] { "Hello", "Open Chrome", "Close", "What is the current time", "Thank You" });
                Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(list));

                try
                {
                    sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                    sre.LoadGrammar(gr);
                    sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
                    sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                    sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Caught");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Exception Caught");
            }
        }
        void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text.ToString())
            {
                case "Hello":
                    ss.SpeakAsync("Hello There");
                    break;
                case "Open Chrome":
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Chrome", "https://www.google.com");
                    break;
                case "Close":
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;
                case "What is the current time":
                    ss.SpeakAsync("Current time is :" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString());
                    break;
                case "Thank You":
                    ss.SpeakAsync("Thank You for using this service");
                    break;
                default:
                    ss.SpeakAsync("Please correct your choice");
                    break;
            }
            txtContents.Text = e.Result.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not an error. It's an exception. All exceptions have names. In this case, `System.NullReferenceException`. This question is a huge duplicate, and will be closed as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Choices list;
```

do

```
Choices list = new Choices();
```

Reason:
You use `list` even before it is initialized.

```
list.Add(new string[] { "Hello", "Open Chrome", "Close", "What is the current time", "Thank You" });
```

Comment: Nikhil, rather than adding another answer, isn't it better to just close as a duplicate?